# Java While(boolean) how this code work?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

**This is the code from lesson on Udemy.**

I don't understand how the `boolean stop;` work in this while loop. I don't see any changes of `stop` inside the loop.

Can some one explain me please how while loop work in this particular case.

```
package socket;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class MultiUserService
{
    public static void main(String [] args) //throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
            System.out.println("wainting for clients...");
            boolean stop = false;
            while(!stop)
            {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("Hello  client!");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String clientInput = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(clientInput);
                input.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            }
            serverSocket.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It will never stop unless an error occurs.

Comment: Classic online training website. Same as Pluralsight. Always filled with errors. Gets me mad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is no change of `stop` in the loop, which means the loop won't ever stop, unless an exception is thrown.

Since it is a server, listening for sockets, this is an expected behavior: the server keeps listening and serving clients.

Note that in production code, there should be a way to stop the server, which, depending on the approach, may or may not require actually stopping that loop (there are asynchronous ways available).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul!

Answer (score 1):

That's the point; once it starts, the loop won't stop unless something goes very wrong.

Comment: That point could also be conveyed less confusingly by `while (true) { ... }`.

Comment: Agreed. Functionally, they're the same though